# LINQ Datacontext Disposal Issues

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am getting a `Cannot access object: DataContext after it's been disposed` in the below DAL method.  I thought that I would be okay calling dispose there.  `result` is an `IEnumurable` and I thought it was `IQueryable` that caused these kinds of problems.

What am I doing wrong?  How **SHOULD** I be disposing of my `DataContext`.  Is there something better to be returning then a `DataTable`?  This is a Desktop app that points at SQL 2005.

Example method that causes this error -->

---

```
    public static DataTable GetEnrolledMembers(Guid workerID)
    {
        var DB = CmoDataContext.Create();

        var AllEnrollees = from enrollment in DB.tblCMOEnrollments
                           where enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID == workerID || enrollment.CMONurseID == workerID
                           join supportWorker in DB.tblSupportWorkers on enrollment.EconomicSupportWorkerID
                               equals supportWorker.SupportWorkerID into workerGroup
                           from worker in workerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select
                               new
                               {
                                   enrollment.ClientID,
                                   enrollment.CMONurseID,
                                   enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID,
                                   enrollment.EnrollmentDate,
                                   enrollment.DisenrollmentDate,
                                   ESFirstName = worker.FirstName,
                                   ESLastName = worker.LastName,
                                   ESPhone = worker.Phone
                               };

        var result = from enrollee in AllEnrollees.AsEnumerable()
                     where (enrollee.DisenrollmentDate == null || enrollee.DisenrollmentDate > DateTime.Now)
                     //let memberName = BLLConnect.MemberName(enrollee.ClientID)
                     let lastName = BLLConnect.MemberLastName(enrollee.ClientID)
                     let firstName = BLLConnect.MemberFirstName(enrollee.ClientID)
                     orderby enrollee.DisenrollmentDate ascending, lastName ascending
                     select
                         new
                         {
                             enrollee.ClientID,
                             //MemberName = memberName,
                             LastName = lastName,
                             FirstName = firstName,
                             NurseName = BLLAspnetdb.NurseName(enrollee.CMONurseID),
                             SocialWorkerName = BLLAspnetdb.SocialWorkerName(enrollee.CMOSocialWorkerID),
                             enrollee.EnrollmentDate,
                             enrollee.DisenrollmentDate,
                             ESWorkerName = enrollee.ESFirstName + " " + enrollee.ESLastName,
                             enrollee.ESPhone
                         };
        DB.Dispose();

        return result.CopyLinqToDataTable();
    }
```

partial class where I create the DataContext -->

---

```
partial class CmoDataContext
{
    public static bool IsDisconnectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return Settings.Default.IsDisconnectedUser;
        }
    }

    public static CmoDataContext Create()
    {
        var cs = IsDisconnectedUser ? Settings.Default.CMOConnectionString : Settings.Default.Central_CMOConnectionString;
        return       new CmoDataContext(cs);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `CopyLinqToDataTable` after disposing the DataContext.  Since LINQ uses deferred execution, it only executes the query when `result` is enumerated, after the DataContext is disposed.

You should put your DataContext in a `using` block that contains the `return` statement.
This will dispose the DataContext after calling `CopyLinqToDataTable`, avoiding the problem.

For example:

```
using(var DB = CmoDataContext.Create()) {
    //Execute queries
    return result.CopyLinqToDataTable();
}
```

The `using` statement generates a `finally` block that disposes the DataContext at the end 
of the `using` block.  (Even if an exception is thrown)

Comment: as long as the return is in the `using` I will be okay??  Thanks

Comment: Yes; you'll be fine.  (Unless you return an `IEnumerable`)

Comment: Okay, out of curiosity, `IEnumerable` will still fail here?  How do you return it then?

Comment: By calling `ToArray`.  Because (again) of deferred execution, if you return an `IEnumerable`, the query won't run until the client (that uses your return value) enumerates it.  By calling `ToArray` and returning that (perhaps wrapped in a `ReadOnlyCollection`), you force the enumerable to be enumerated immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You should use something like `ToList` in queries before calling `Dispose`

Comment: Can `List` bind to `DataGrids` and the like as well as `DataTable`?  If so I will look into it.  Is the term I am looking for "concrete" as far as my return type?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this instead?

```
...
DataTable dt = result.CopyLinqToDataTable(); 
DB.Dispose(); 
return dt;
```